# TIN Interpolation in QGIS creates weird lines?

Tags: qgis, error, interpolation, tin

I am using TIN Interpolation to interpolate point features based on their cost attribute (value is between 0 and 5000). Graduated symbology creates something like this:

[image]

However when I am using TIN interpolation, I get these weird white stripes (image below). I've been trying for hours to get rid of them. They really look out of place..

[image]

Anyone have an idea how to get rid of these?

Comment: Which tool or algorithm did you use?

Comment: I used Raster > Interpolation > Triangular Interpolation in QGIS. I think its GDAL tools

Answer (score 2):

I have had similar problems when interpolating data of a scanned image which I imported in a WGS84 projection using its pixel-coordinates (for practical reasons). The points I used for the interpolation were about 0.010 units apart. I retried after multiplying all coordinates by a factor 10^6, and the problem was gone. If this also works for you, it is likely due to precision/rounding applied in the interpolation code, so hen please make an issue for it on [hub.qgis.org](http://hub.qgis.org)!